# HTTP Cookie Seting

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

Before I tested this I deleted all the cookies for this particular site.
I use Opera Dragonfly to view all the requests and responses and I do check requests/responses for all that is on that page, .js files, images etc... Not just the main page.

So part of first "no-cookie" request looks like this:

```
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: hr-BA,hr;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

No cookies sent which is right. Than I check for responses and in the main page response I see the following cookies set:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=216803B3E23C354660AF83BECC02C364.atg05-prd-atg2; Domain=.hyatt.com; Path=/
Set-Cookie: ATG_SESSION_ID=216803B3E23C354660AF83BECC02C364.atg05-prd-atg2; Path=/
Set-Cookie: NSC_xxx.izbuu.dpn_80=ffffffffd28f336545525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660;expires=Tue, 10-Jun-2014 21:28:01 GMT;path=/
```

Than two more in the some JavaScript .js file response:

```
Set-Cookie: surfaid=1468792b5fd; Domain=.hyatt.com; Expires=Fri, 16-Feb-2046 22:44:36 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: NSC_xxx.izbuu.dpn_80=ffffffffd28f336545525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660;expires=Tue, 10-Jun-2014 21:28:09 GMT;path=/
```

But of that two one is the same so actually there is one more new cookie.

Now I go to the same page again and when viewing the request I see all those cookies that are set before are sent of course.
But the reason I'm asking this question is that I see another one:

```
mbox=check#true#1402433952|session#1402433891564-659640#1402435752|PC#1402433891564-659640.26_01#1403643502
```

When did this one get set and how?

Comment: someone is performing cookie magic on the server side

Comment: Are you using any tracking or A/B testing javascript includes from Omniture Test and Target? Look for a  mbox.js include.  See some reference to mbox here: http://www.webmetric.org/test_and_target_part5.php?jump_id=0102

Comment: @Scott Shelby yes looks like it.

Comment: @ledlogic no I only use Opera Dragonfly. There is a mbox.js include in the page source. Is there any way I can get this cookie by using PHP CURL when I write script that sends data to this page?

Comment: I don't think so, the cookie is for a different domain, only when rendered in a browser.  The page in a browser has access to the cookie value, but unless you have a php tool to render a virtual browser and have it return the browser cookies, you wouldn't be able to access it.  In actual browser clients you could write additional script to retransmit the value cookie back to your server.

Comment: @ledlogic thanks man. Do you know of the any php virtual browser with full javascript support?